# Regex for parse name with one or more words after double number and before 2 or more spaces

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, text

Problem:
   How create regex to parse "DISNAY LAND 2.0 GCP" like name from Array of lines in Scala like this:

```
DE1ALAT0002  32.4756  -86.4393  106.1 ZQ DISNAY LAND 2.0 GCP             23456

//For using in code:


val regex = """(?:[\d\.\d]){2}\s*(?:[\d.\d])\s*(ZQ)\s*([A-Z])""".r . // my attempt
  val getName = row match {
    case regex(name) => name
    case _ =>
  }
```

I'm sure only in:

1) there is different number of spaces between values
2) useful value "DISNAY LAND 2.0 GCP" come after double number and "ZQ" letters
3) name separating with one space and may consist of one or many words
4) name ending with two or more spaces

sorry if I repeat the question, but after a long search I did not find the right solution

Many thank for answers

Comment: So what are the rules around the  "ZQ" thing? will it always be ZQ or just two letters, or something else?

Comment: Thx for answer! For the strings to be extracted - always ZQ - but there can also be other 2 letters, for example, SE,  YU, etc. - but they may not exist and instead of them 2 or more spaces

Comment: You can add a few input/output examples to make it more clear.

Comment: thanks a bunch - it works for me correctly, at least now )))

Answer (score 0):

You may use an *`.unanchored`* pattern like

```
\d\.\d+\s+ZQ\s+(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y1shE8/2). **Details**

- `\d\.\d+` - 1 digit, `.` and then 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `ZQ` - `ZQ` substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (here, the left-hand side context definition ends, now, starting to capture the value we need to return)
- `(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\s\S+)*` - a non-capturing group that matches 0 or more sequences of a single whitespace (`\s`) and then 1+ non-whitespace chars (so, up to the double whitespace or end of string).

[Scala demo](https://rextester.com/OIQ94372):

```
val regex = """\d\.\d+\s+ZQ\s+(\S+(?:\s\S+)*)""".r.unanchored
val row = "DE1ALAT0002  32.4756  -86.4393  106.1 ZQ DISNAY LAND 2.0 GCP             23456"
val getName = row match {
  case regex(name) => name
  case _ =>
}
print(getName)
```

Output: `DISNAY LAND 2.0 GCP`